# Use Javascript variable in element's style property

Tags: javascript

```
function move(direction, el) {
    el.style.direction = (el.style.direction+10)+'px';
}
```

I have this very simple function that moves an element by 10 pixels in a specified direction. Now it errors if i use this, I'm thinking I can't use direction as a variable in this situation. Is this right?

Comment: And what error? Do we need to guess?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the style property like this:

```
function move(direction, el) {
    el.style[direction] = (el.style.direction+10)+'px';
}
```

As long as `direction` is a string.